# sudoku recursion: exactly where and how does the backtracking occur?

Tags: c++, recursion

I am working on writing my own Sudoku Code in c++ with a few requirements for an assignment. It must use recursion and a vector of vectors. I think I generally understand the c++ language part but I do not get logic in part of the backtrack process.  My pseudocode will pass my i,j position  to other functions in another class as well as the value k(choice of 1-9). Let's say I am 3 iterations in my solve, I reach a square for which I have checked all values 1-9 and none of them work. Now I set this to zero and have to backtrack,and go to the previous square/iteration I worked on and try a different value to proceeded with, come back to the square I was on and check again.

My exact question is this: Where in my code can there be this move back to the previous square? I am not seeing how to fit this in or how this works in these loops? If I don't go back one, then my code will find the same square again and run through all 9 choices, fail, and go back again in an infinite recursion? I am terrified to start testing runs of this code for fear of infinite recursive loops. My pseudocode is as follows:

```
      bool Board::solveBoard()
  {
Board board;
if(board.isComplete())
{
    board.display();
    return true;
}
for(int i=ZERO;i<NINE;++i)//iterate through row vectors
{
    for (int j=ZERO;j<NINE;++j)//iterate through column vectors
    {
      if(board.getSquare(i,j)==ZERO)//find first value equal to zero
      {
        for(int k=ONE;k<=NINE;++k)//iterate through values 1-9 to fill square and check board
        {
        board.setSquare(i,j,k);//assign k=1 to 9
          if(board.isLegal(i,j,k))//check if value is legal
          {
            if(solveBoard)  return true;
          }
          board.unsetSquare(i,j);//otherwise remove value in backtracking?
        }//end # 1-9 iteration
      }//end get square-check square loop
      return false;//I think this is where the program will go back a step to the last value worked previously
    }//end column iteration
}//end row iteration
```

} // bool Board::solveBoard()

The notation ZERO, NINE etc is a requirement by the instructor as "magic numbers" to be capitalized.  I have read that infinite recursion can fill up computer memory and crash it so that is why I was worried. I am just trying to identify where the backtracking to previous step actually occurs?I put a return false towards the bottom that will return false in the column iteration. Will this then tell the iteration to go back to the previous j value and try again- and how will it fill it with a different number other than starting with the number one just like it did before?

Comment: *"I am terrified to start testing runs of this code for fear of infinite recursive loops"* - it's not going to make your computer explode. Just run it and if it gets stuck, terminate the program, debug, and start again.

Comment: `int k=ONE;k<=NINE;++k)` seems rather pointless using macros for hthe values

Comment: [Did you try a search before asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bc%2b%2b%5dsudoku%20recursion) :P ...

Comment: Where are `i` and `j` being changed?

Comment: I did in fact search and read extensively on the topic....the best example found in a stanford class, the problem is everyone generalizes code and the process but no one explains in detail where the "go back to previous" backtrack step actually occurs...and hence my post. I also searched on here as well and read through about a dozen posts:)